# div will not center in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm building a bootstrap site and i have divs in the center of the page that i am trying to make centered. I can't for the life of me figure it out. Anyone have any idea why it won't center? I've tried:

```
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
```

in almost ever element and i can't get it going. Feeling frustrated here. Here's a link to the site so you could see what i'm talking about http://bit.ly/1wYQDD1

Here's what part of the code looks like, you can inspect it at the site to see more:

```
    <section class="no-margin" id="main" style="background-image:url(/GulflifeRealty.com/images/images/<%=img%>); height:650px; background-size:cover;  background-position:0 -210px; background-repeat:no-repeat;">    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">

            <div>

                <a href="http://matrix.swflamls.com/Matrix/Public/IDXSearch.aspx?count=1&idx=f25b59c&iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]"><div class="homeBox" style="background-image:url(/GulflifeRealty.com/images/images/<%=listings%>);">

                <h3>See our Listings</h3>


                </div></a>

                <a href="http://matrix.swflamls.com/Matrix/Public/IDXSearch.aspx?count=1&idx=b03d59b&iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]"><div class="homeBox" style="background-image:url(/GulflifeRealty.com/images/images/<%=mls%>);">
<h3>Search the MLS</h3>
```

```
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't able to center the two `<div>`'s using `text-align: center` because you're using `float: left` to make them appear inline. You need to to use `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left`, like this:

```
.homeBox {
     display: inline-block;
     float: none;
}
```

And then set the `text-align` property of the container `<div>` to `center`, like this:

```
row > div {
     text-align: center;
}
```

It works perfectly:

[image]

Comment: WOW!!!!! I have this love hate relationship with CSS. Thanks for clearing that up. I'll accept when this thing lets me (7 minutes)